# Creating min. date and max. date columns based on Quarter, Month, YTD

Tags: r, date

I have a data frame like the following:

```
Frequency  Period   Period No.  Year
Monthly    1        1           2018
Quarterly  Q1       3           2018
YTD        YTD-Feb  2           2019
```

Based on these columns, I'd like to add a min. date and max. date column so that the data frame looks like this:

```
Frequency  Period   Period No.  Year  Min. Date  Max. Date
Monthly    1        1           2018  1/1/2018   1/31/2018
Quarterly  Q1       3           2018  1/1/2018   3/31/2018
YTD        YTD-Feb  2           2019  1/1/2019   2/28/2019
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If we need the max, min based on the 'PeriodNo.' column, create a sequence of Dates by month from the 'Year' column, then extract the  `min` and max`

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(lubridate)
library(stringr)
df1 %>% 
   mutate(date = map2(as.Date(str_c(Year, '-01-01')), 
   PeriodNo., ~ seq(.x, length.out = .y, by = '1 month')), 
   Min.Date =   do.call(c, map(date, min)), 
   Max.Date = do.call(c, map(date, ~ceiling_date(max(.x), 'month')-1))) %>% 
   select(-date)
#  Frequency  Period PeriodNo. Year   Min.Date   Max.Date
#1   Monthly       1         1 2018 2018-01-01 2018-01-31
#2 Quarterly      Q1         3 2018 2018-01-01 2018-03-31
#3       YTD YTD-Feb         2 2019 2019-01-01 2019-02-28
```

---

Or an option with `Map`

```
lst1 <- Map(function(x, y) seq(as.Date(paste0(x, "-01-01")), 
    length.out = y, by = '1 month'), df1$Year, df1$PeriodNo.)
df1$Min.Date <- do.call(c, lapply(lst1, min))
df1$Max.Date <- do.call(c, lapply(lst1, function(x) (max(x) + months(1) -1)) )
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Frequency = c("Monthly", "Quarterly", "YTD"), 
    Period = c("1", "Q1", "YTD-Feb"), PeriodNo. = c(1L, 3L, 2L
    ), Year = c(2018L, 2018L, 2019L)), class = "data.frame",
    row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: I'm getting this error: Error in ceiling(length.out) : 
  non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Comment: @AliceWang are  you using the same data in my post

Comment: Yes - I'm using the same data. The only difference I see is that I don't have the 'L' following Period No. and Year values. I tried your alternate solution and got the same error. I checked the column types, and it's saying that Period No. is being recognized as character and Year as double.

Comment: Converted to numeric and your solution worked. Thank you!